# reference ${user.home} in Spring Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration

In xml configuration I can do the following:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="file:${user.home}/.config}/api.properties"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true"
        system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

In java configuration I would do the following:

```
/**
 * @return a {@link org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer} so that placeholders are correctly populated
 * @throws Exception exception if the file is not found or cannot be opened or read
 */
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws Exception {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new UrlResource[]
            {new UrlResource("file:${user.home}/.config/api.properties")};
    propConfig.setLocations(resources);
    propConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    propConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propConfig;
}
```

However this doesn't understand ${user.home}

Comment: Someone has upvoted this today so I don't see how the fact that it is a duplicate matters, clearly this currently has the correct answer to solve the problem.  Also I can't find a duplicate, can the moderators please provide a link?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of "Change user.home system property", as mentioned above! It is related, but not the same! Please remove the duplicate banner, or provide a proper link to a similar question.

Comment: This is Not a duplicate, it is specifically referring to  use of  Properties in Spring which has its own syntax and configuration attributes see http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `${sys:user.home}` to refer system property. For system environment use `${env:THE-ENV-VAR-NAME}`

Comment: doesn't work

    <context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT" order="-1" location="file:${env:user.home}/managed/latest/bin/rm-app.properties" />

Comment: @Arun BC, if it does not work *for you* this is not a reason for downvoting. The reason in your case is that you want to use system variable `user.home` and therefore should use syntax `${sys:user.home}`. You however turn to environment variable that obviously does not exist.